# Есть ли возможность привести результат запроса linq к "конкретному типу" не используя "класс-посредник"?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

Например у меня есть linq запрос в каком-нибудь методе в котором объединяются 2 таблицы, и выбирается содержимое всех столбцов из двух таблиц:

```
var result = from a in db.tb1
             join b in db.tb2
             on a.tb1.tb1FK equals tb2.idPK
             select new {все поля}.ToList();
```

Переменная result получится неопределенного типа. И я не смогу ее использовать, например в другом методе без загрузки результатов в класс посредник, чья коллекция объектов могла бы хранить результаты.

Comment: Может быть использовать Tuple<T1,T2>, ведь tb1 и tb2 определены моделью ?

Comment: Раз вы используете EF, а не linq to objects то как минимум вы должны либо использовать IEnumerable (отказавшись от выгод IQuerable, расчёта на сервере), либо должны описать запрос в терминах классов классов которые сервер знает и/или использовать анонимные (и стараться максимально отложить момент .AsEnumerable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
List<(String Name, Int32 Id)> result = (from a in db.tb1
            join 
              b in db.tb2
            on a.tb1.tb1FK equals tb2.idPK
select (a.Name, a.Id)).ToList();
```